# Mapping sockjs-client in systemjs

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, sockjs

I'm using typescript and angular2 and I want to use SockJS in my project. I run: `npm install sockjs-client`. Now I want to add mapping of `node_modules/sockjs-client` in `systemjs.config.js`. It is how the file looks now:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'sockjs-client': 'npm:sockjs-client',
            'stompjs': 'npm:stompjs/lib/stomp.min.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

And I've the following exception in the browser:

```
localhost/:16 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8080/node_modules/sockjs-client(…)
```

What is the proper systemjs mapping for sockjs-client library?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'sockjs-client': 'npm:sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js'
```